# How to convert the char array to unsigned int?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, unsigned-integer

I have the following code:

```
volatile unsigned int * address;
char * array="0x10000008";
```

Please tell me, what is a correct way of writing the "array" value to "address" variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `sscanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

sscanf(array, "%p", &address);
```

or `strtoull`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

address = (unsigned int *)strtoull(array, NULL, 0);
```